# jQuery mousemove erratic movements and jumpy results in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, mousemove

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/atlchris/CC53T/

What this does is it takes the jQuery UI slider and adds hover & preview support to it. It works great on most browsers but on Firefox for Mac, I am getting jumpy results and erratic movements.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work better across all browsers?

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari for Mac.

Comment: Always consider looking for mathematical ways of calculating repetitive code, also try to condense else if structures. Here's a quick version of reorganized logic: http://jsfiddle.net/CC53T/1/

Comment: @TheZ thanks for the logic tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another resource, I was able to solve the problem by using the `mouseleave` event instead of `mouseout`. The `mouselease` doesn't fire on internal elements.